# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, spring-roo, m2e

I switched from **q4e Helios** to **Indigo m2e** plugin and my Maven 2 project no longer works. I had a ROO-generated Spring MVC project.

This is what I get:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:test-compile (execution: default, phase: process-test-sources)
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (execution: default, phase: process-sources)
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-spring?

Comment: Thanks @Raghuram. In the end I was not able to make it work with Indigo and M2. I ended up downloading STS from Spring which is Helios based and everything worked as EXPECTED. M2 + Indigo is a nightmare to deal with, anyone reading it should really stay away from this combo for now in my opinion.

Comment: If you do not want to understand the [backgroud](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) of this error message you can at lease use the QuickFix provided by eclipse indigo to insert the relevant parts in the pom.xml to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you upgraded to m2e plugin from version 0.xx  to version 1.0 thats probably what caused the issues you are having, This may be helpful (it is intended for SpringSuource Tool Suite but I fixed an regular Eclipse following the advices at the end on the section called **"Uh oh…my projects no longer build"**);

http://blog.springsource.com/2011/10/18/upgrading-maven-integration-for-springsource-tool-suite-2-8-0/