# Plugin error: execution not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse, m2e

I am trying to use the maven-warpath-plugin [available here](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin). But I keep getting an error in my pom.xml file that says:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.appfuse.plugins:maven-warpath-plugin:2.1.0:add-classes (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

How do I resolve this? Here is my pom.xml snippet for the plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.appfuse.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-warpath-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-classes</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Eclipse offers me a quickfox tip to "discover new m2e connectors" to resolve this error. I have installed most of the connectors available that seem to apply but the error is still there. Any ideas how I could make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the new [behaviour](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered) of m2e (which replaced the old m2eclipse plugin). To specify what eclipse should do with the plugin you have to configure the build lifecycle mapping in the project's pom.xml - or install a connector (which decides if the plugin needs to be executed in an eclipse build or not) if it exists.

As there seems to be no connector for the maven-warpath-plugin yet you have to define the behaviour in the pom. You can use the second eclipse quickfix for this (*Permamnently mark goal add-classes in pom.xml as ignored in eclipse build*). This will add the following section to your pom:

```
<build>
    ......
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.appfuse.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-warpath-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.1.0,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-classes</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

You can change the `<ignore>` action to `<execute>` if you want to process the plugin in each eclipse build (on `import`, `clean`, ...).

The plugin configuration is eclipse specific and does not make the pom.xml look nicer - but at least it has no influence on the Maven build....

Comment: @FrVaBe does the second eclipse quickfix for this (Permamnently mark goal add-classes in pom.xml as ignored in eclipse build). can affect my web application execution??

Comment: @Amira Manai It should not affect the execution as it has no influence on the maven build.

Comment: As far as I can see in my tests, that approach is directly omitting maven-warpath-plugin from the Maven build, isn't it? I mean, I expect to receive a `<type>warpath</type>` artifact as a dependency in my main war, which it can't be identified.

Comment: @Xtreme Biker I am not sure what you mean by "omitting maven-warpath-plugin" - The pluginManagement section has no influence on the build - it just eliminates the eclipse error message. I do not know if there is a connector available yet for the maven-warpath-plugin. This would make this section unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Also see the answer [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Answer (score 0):

Error pom.xml: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process

my project is ProjectA, it's created by maven version 3.3.3 and i used eclipse version 4.5. But when install eclipse version 2021 - 4.20, then I open projectA on eclipse (version 4.20) errors appear in pom.xml: error detail: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.3:process (execution: process, phase: process-resources)

I don't know why appears on eclipse's new version 4.20. Error appear "execution"

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.3.3</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>process</id>
    <goals>
      <goal>process</goal>
    </goals>
    <phase>process-resources</phase>
    <configuration>
```

Thank you very much for help!