# Eclipse Maven archtetype won't build: Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping

Tags: maven, jax-rs, resteasy

I won't lie, I'm pretty frustrated here.  I am trying to set up a webapp-jee6 maven archetype in eclipse. I'm doing nothing but selecting the archetype, and on an empty project, it's giving me errors.

Not sure how to even begin debugging this short of reading an entire Maven book.  Cannot believe such a common operation would fail.  Maven is the recommended way to set up Resteasy, and many projects, but it has never saved me time nor reduced complexity.

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy (execution: default, phase: validate)    pom.xml /mojo   line 53 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a well known behaviour of the (new) maven eclipse integration plugin (m2e) since eclipse Indigo. It needs information how to handle the maven plugin during an "eclipse build".

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7392705/367285) answer from me.