# How can I get m2e plugin to ignore resource filtering when writing eclipse .classpath

Tags: maven, classpath, m2eclipse, m2e

When m2e(1.1.0) in eclipse(indigo) updates project configuration it changes the entry for my resources folder to exclude all.

```xml
<classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="conf"/>
```

But I need the following for tests to run successfully:

```xml
<classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="conf"/>
```

I want to exclude some resources from my jar (e.g., license.foo) but I need many of these files to be on the eclipse classpath to enable test execution.

What's the right approach to resolve this problem?

- Are there settings to org.eclipse.m2e in my pom to change the behavior?
- Can I add text to the .project/.classpath to inform m2e that this must remain?
- Should I use profiles to alter what gets stored in the jars?

How have you approached this class of problem?
(FYI this is similar to [MNGECLIPSE-864](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-864))

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place resources that you need at runtime to

```
src/main/resources
```

and resources that you only need for testing to

```
src/test/resources
```

This is the [Maven Standard Directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and the resources will be on the classpath.

If you have not standard directories you should use the [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/) to [add additional (test) resource directories](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html#Add_more_resource_directories_to_your_project).

Comment: So, do I need to install the m2e buildhelper connector and then only list the build helper plugin in my pluginManagement section to make sure it is used by m2e but not my standard build?

Comment: What is your _standard_ build? If you need resources during your test that are not located in `src/test/resources` your maven build will fail. That is not an eclipse issue. To make it work you can configure the build-helper-plugin with the configuration you need in your build/plugin section - and to make it error free in eclipse you have to care about the [lifecycle mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7392705/367285) (installing the connector would be the best).

Comment: I have a difference between the command-line build where conf/resources are added to the top level of the jar without the "conf" subdirectory and eclipse which uses "conf/" prefix to the resources.  Therefore, eclipse cannot locate the resources.   I need to bring these two into alignment or allow eclipse to make a 2nd copy.  The first option seems like the better one

Answer (score 0):

If you run into this problem then you might want to ask **"why would I want eclipse and command line maven to handle resources differently."**

I assumed this problem grew out of a desire to keep unwanted items (e.g., license file) out of the shipping jar.  However, as **FrVaBe** point's out about **test resources** nicely satisfy this need.

I did some digging through assembly files and poms to find out that rival specifications between them moved the conf directory into target/classes, ignored it and imported the original-source location into the pom.  I unwound the complexity and have a simpler pom which handles resources in a more standard way.

Thanks for the help

Peter