# Import Maven Project to Eclipse and Fix the errors

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

I made imported a project to eclipse
and I have a lot of errors in every class name even classes like String ...

the error in the classes I made is `Implicit super constructor Object() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor`

and inside the methods `<Class> cannot be resolved to a type`
even to IOException I am getting `IOException cannot be resolved to a type`

so what should I do ?
I tried to build , clean again with no use

UPDATE : also I am getting Description

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)   pom.xml /test line 6    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Comment: check if maven failed to download dependencies.

Comment: how can I do that ?
update dependencies ?

Comment: Go to Project->Properties->Java build path->Libraries. 

Is the JRE System Library added? Does it point to the correct location?

Comment: in pom.xml file. it will have list of dependencies. see if all are downloaded under .m2 folder in %user% folder in windows.

Comment: @Raze2dust I am getting Build path entry is missing: org.ec....launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.7

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-spring)

Comment: @sudmong sorry this is the first time I am using mavan , I have the dependices on the lib under WEB-INF in webapp folder , should I added them manually to pom.xml

I am using OS X
Thanks

Comment: How did you import to Maven? Did you try `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. I think you have directly imported them. Try doing `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Comment: error in pom.xml /test line 6

Comment: I just tried it , it gives me build faild , I have the file it has only one class for entites

Comment: What precisely did you do to 'make imported'? Without this no one can help you.

Comment: my friend sent me the zipped file , I tried to import it using eclipse maven plugin but I am getting these errors
I tried to make mvn eclipse:eclipse and even mvn package
 but I am getting build faild

Answer (score 18):

The project that you imported is a Maven project. What you should do is open the pom.xml file located in the root of the project and add the following plugin in the plugin management part of the file:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>resources</goal>
                                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore />
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Then right click the project, go to Maven and Update project configuration.

This should fix it.

Comment: This is "hard fix", thank you for it. But this problem was and is not present in other Eclipse + m2e installations (such as with my colleagues). Can you explain why this problem has appeared?

Comment: Nevermind, I read this POS here http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered I'm very dissatisfied with this lifecycle mapping thing.

Comment: Probably easier to re-import the Maven project — Then you get a dialog where you can choose “Do not Execute” to fill in the pom.

Answer (score 4):

I think that your problem is not in maven project and not in import procedure but in your eclipse configuration. It seems that your eclipse "does not see" correct JDK.

So, first try to create the simple "hello world" project and see if it works. When this works import your maven project again, i.e. run command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and then open the project using eclipse. If this is your first eclipse project you have to create M2_REPO variable that will refer to your maven repository (`USER_HOME/.m2/repository`)

If you still have problems try to refresh and clean the project.

If the problem still happens compare which JDK are you using in "good" and "bad" project. I believe that you will see difference there. So, fix it.

Comment: I have a simple class with few fields called entity , i tried to use mvn eclipse:eclipse but I am getting No plugin found for prefix 'eclipse' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re

Answer (score 3):

Were you able to build the project successfully..
If so, don't import it..again run @ project root level;

```
#mvn eclipse:eclipse -o
```

This will create a eclipse project.Then 'import as existing project.' All classpath problem will get solved..But you need to set your .m2 home as a variable in your build path..

Comment: I am getting [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'eclipse' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/Users/comp/.m2/repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Try updating your maven install..I forgot the command..It is something like; #mvn update... and again try to build the project

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Project`->`Properties`->`Java build path`->`Libraries`. Is the JRE System Library added? Does it point to the correct location?

Also try running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on the root folder of the project (You will need to download maven and add it to the classpath first).

Comment: `mvn eclise:eclipse` is what did it for me, thank you.  Dunno why I had to do it on this checkout and not on any other checkouts.