# Error when importing Maven-GWT project ("No marketplace entries found to handle gwt-maven-plugin")

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven

I'm using Eclipse Indigo on Win XP, Maven 3.0.3 and GWT 2.4.  I created a Maven-GWT project using the `Mavne gwt archetype`.  Then I opened Eclipse, went to `File -> Import`, selected `Existing Maven Projects`, chose the pom for my GWT-Maven project, and then got this dialog:

[image]

The errors are

```
No marketplace entries found to handle gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:generateAsync in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
No marketplace entries found to handle gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:i18n in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
No marketplace entries found to handle maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
```

Anyone know how to resolve these errors?  It is wreaking havoc when I actually import my project and try and work with it. - Dave

Comment: Google mandated that you must use Android Studio for android development a few years ago. That pretty much killed eclipse. They now also mandate using Kotlin.

Answer (score 25):

Make sure you are not using the embedded Maven of Eclipse.

Go to `Window->Preference ->Maven -> Installation->`choose your own maven installation folder there.

#### EDIT

If your company pays for IDE, you should ask for [IntelliJ the IDE for  Java](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), which I would say is better than Eclipse in many ways, not saying Eclipse is not good, that's just a good alternative. And you won't have this issue to start with

Comment: @rapt It's no magic, if you don't set it there, Eclipse will picks up the embedded Maven that comes with itself which won't work.

Comment: hi Gob00st, I have set installation as my maven installation folder.(when I do  mvn --version, it is written Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\bin\..) and I set it as C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9-bin\ but it still does not work. could ypu please help me? thank you

Comment: I don't think suggesting a different IDE is a solution, just let the people use their IDE of choice...

Answer (score 6):

If your pom is not specific as to the version of the maven-resources-plugin, that version will come from the superpom. By default, m2e uses an embedded copy of Maven 3.0.x. If the superpom there points to 2.4.3 and your 'outside-of-Eclipse' version asks for something else, then the Maven inside of Eclipse will go looking for 2.4.3 and fail due to the 'offline'.

Fix by configuring m2e to use the Maven installation you are using outside, or turning off 'offline' for one build.

If you want to use maven from your local installation instead of the embedded version that comes with m2e, You have to do this

```
Windows ==> Preferences ==> Maven ==> Installations ==> Click Add (select your local maven installation directory)
```

**Installation Directory is not where local repository. It is where maven is installed.**

After changing try right click on project then,

> Maven ----> Update Project

Comment: If this is not give correct solution. Then try to create a eclipse project in manual way mvn eclipse:eclipse

Answer (score 2):

See [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin/6475103#6475103)

You can basically just copy the snippet from http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven#POM_changes_needed_for_Eclipse_Indigo and adapt to your plugins and goals.

Comment: Hi, I cut and pasted the plugin pom changes from your link, but when I went to import my existing Maven project, I got the same errors I included in the dialog above.  Does your answer pertain to importing an existing Maven project created with the GWT-maven archetype ?

Comment: Oh, not created with the artifact no. Sorry, missed that on your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a different approach with maven, gwt and eclipse.

I am using the maven eclipse plugin to generate a .classpath and .project file and import the project manually into eclipse (not as a maven project).

My configuration for the maven eclipse plugin looks like this:

```xml
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>

            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                <buildOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</buildOutputDirectory>
                <projectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</projectnature>
                    <projectnature>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppNature</projectnature>

                    <nature>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtNature</nature>
                </projectnatures>
                <buildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.webAppProjectValidator</buildcommand>

                    <buildcommand>com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.projectValidator</buildcommand>
                    <buildcommand>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.gwtProjectValidator</buildcommand>
                </buildcommands>
                <classpathContainers>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>

                    <classpathContainer>com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.GWT_CONTAINER</classpathContainer>
                </classpathContainers>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com.google.gwt:gwt-servlet</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.gwt:gwt-user</exclude>
                    <exclude>com.google.gwt:gwt-dev</exclude>
                    <exclude>javax.validation:validation-api</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <linkedResources>
                    <linkedResource>
                        <name>war</name>
                        <type>2</type>
                        <location>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</location>
                    </linkedResource>
                </linkedResources>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried this.  As with the original poster, I first had 3 errors.  Now, I have one.

Comment: I tried plugin configuration you suggest.  As with the original poster, I first had 3 errors.  Now, I have just one:  "No marketplace entries found to handle maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information."  I tried adding a dependency for it.  And it is in the Maven repository.  So the message doesn't exactly make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me:

1. Delete the project from eclipse (but don't delete from disk)
2. Close eclipse
3. In your user folder there is .m folder.
4. Delete repository folder underneath it (.m/repository).
5. Open eclipse Import project as existing maven project (from disk).