# Error Importing existing Maven Project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I'm trying to use **documents4j** in order to convert a Doc file to PDF. I followed all [these instructions at documents4j.com](http://documents4j.com/#/develop) and I don't get any error from command line, but when I import the project from Eclipse, I get this error

[image: screen shot]

I'm not an expert on Maven because is my first project with it, so I'm sorry  if the question seems too easy for some of you.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916308/error-when-importing-maven-gwt-project-no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle).

Comment: I assume you won't have any problem. Press "Finish" and try building from command line.

Comment: If I press Finish I got this : `Continuing with import will results in projects with build errors, please see the help for more information`. Then All. the projects(of documents4j) have errors.

Comment: Maven / Eclipse is a pain, ever since m2eclipse became m2e. Get IntelliJ or NetBeans and you'll be fine :-)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I started this project with Eclipse and I have to finish with Eclipse.