# Unable to create maven project in eclipse(oxygen) ide throws error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am unable create a maven project, throws error as below,

maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (1 errors)

maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (1 errors)

maven-compiler-plugin:2.6:resources (1 errors)

maven-compiler-plugin:2.6:testResources (1 errors)

Could you please help me on this.

[errorScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyPVm.png)

Thanks in advance,
Maduraipandian M.

Comment: Are these errors in the project named "sample" ? I ask because that one does not look like a Maven project, in your screen capture...

Comment: Looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916308/error-when-importing-maven-gwt-project-no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle Can you let us know if any of those answers help?

Comment: Hi @moilejter,

Thanks for the response!

The error with the project named "flipkart" above to "sample", errors popup once the project is created.

Please review and help.

Thanks again in advance,
Maduraipandian Manivel.

Comment: Hi @Deancoakley coakley,

Thanks for the response!

Let me check and will update you.

Thanks again,
Maduraipandian Manivel.

Comment: @Deancoakley, I tried the workaround in the link you mentioned, but still throwing the same error.
Workaround tried,
#1
Delete the project from eclipse (but don't delete from disk)
Close eclipse
In your user folder there is .m folder.
Delete repository folder underneath it (.m/repository).
Open eclipse Import project as existing maven project (from disk). 
#2
Installed maven externally then followed the below steps,
Go to Window->Preference ->Maven -> Installation->choose your own maven installation folder there.
Please review and help.
Thanks in advance,
Maduraipandian Manivel.