# No marketplace entries found to handle avro-maven-plugin:1.8.2:idl-protocol in Eclipse. Please see Help for more information

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, avro, m2eclipse

IDE used ECLIPSE
I am trying to pull in a project which has AVRO schema compilation using IDL protocol.
I am getting below error by Maven.

Solutions tried  :
[Error when importing Maven-GWT project ("No marketplace entries found to handle gwt-maven-plugin")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7916308/error-when-importing-maven-gwt-project-no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle/25540809) and thats not working for me.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${avro.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                            <goal>protocol</goal>
                            <goal>idl-protocol</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/avro</sourceDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad, i went through all setup videos and all were using IntelliJ . In eclipse you need to go to Run As -> Maven build  and give compile. This will create the needed AVRO classes in suitable location as mentioned in pom.xml. Exception went after that