# How to build Protobuf for Java in Windows via Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I download the source Protobuf zip file. Then I open up my Classic Eclipse and choose File->Import->Existing Maven Projects.

I choose the root folder to be /java. It shows that pom.xml has been ticked, choose Next.

The screen says: Setup Maven plugin connectors: with

```
maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (2 errors):
No marketplace entries found to handle maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run in Eclipse. Please see Help for more information.
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: The java project has nothing special. Try using 'mvn' command line to build it.

Answer (score 6):

You can ignore that error. But when the import process finish probably you will get:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (execution:
>   generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)

If so, reason is that your current configuration doesn't support maven-antrun. You can find a related question here: [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

An explanation of the problem can be found here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Easy way to solve? Adding the next block of code to your pom.xml:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <execute>
                  <runOnIncremental>false</runOnIncremental>
                </execute>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

After some usual update Maven project configuration, clear and rebuild all, pom problem disappear.

But then you will get probably some error about missing classes. You must [download](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list) the protoc binary and execute it for **all** the .proto files you can find on your sources directory. Example:

```
protoc --java_out=src/main/java -I../src ..\ src\google\protobuf\descriptor.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a bash script to help you compile all of those proto files. Execute the script in the java directory.

```
#/bin/bash
for proto_file in ../src/google/protobuf/*.proto; do
    echo "generating java source from $proto_file"
    protoc --java_out=core/src/main/java -I../src $proto_file
done
```