# Unable to create maven project in STS

Tags: java, maven

I'm not able to create a maven project in sts which results in proper directory structure. Although all required steps are done, I get a window saying `"Setup Maven plugin Connectors"`. Please help me figure out the problem.

[image]

Comment: Your question is duplicate and it answered here :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383085/setup-maven-plugin-connectors-error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup Maven plugin connectors Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383085/setup-maven-plugin-connectors-error)