# How to migrate selenium maven project to another computer

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have selenium webdriver maven TestNG project in computer 1. I would like to migrate the project to the computer 2. Computer 2 has Eclipse installed already.

I downloaded the project folder from computer 1.

Unzipped it.

In computer 2, I imported the project (File > Import).

I see errors in pom.xml.

Build path also shows blank.

[Img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGtwq.png)

[img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYHsm.png)

[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGHmS.png)

[img4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nq4im.png)

How can I migrate selenium webdriver maven project from one machine to a different machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup Maven plugin connectors Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383085/setup-maven-plugin-connectors-error)

Answer (score 0):

After I run the commands, it worked.

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```