# How do I use Jooq source generation with M2E?

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, m2e, jooq

I'm trying to configure Jooq source generation to work with Maven in Eclipse (I use M2E), but I'm running into a problem when following the Jooq manual.

Here is the relevant part of my pom.xml: https://gist.github.com/cfd8a0556dd441ab43ff

The error is: Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:2.0.5:generate (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)

It occurs on line 12 of the gist snippet above.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [corresponding ME2 wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#execute_plugin_goal) page. You need to explicitly configure IDE build-time bindings for your plugin to execute certain goals during build. Alternatively you can implement [M2E configurator](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#delegate_to_a_project_configurator_.28recommended.29) for your Maven plugin that could take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Eugene also stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794626/521799), this is quite a common problem with the official implementation of M2E. The source code generation phase in the build lifecycle seems to cause a lot of trouble.

I generally suggest using the [Apache / Sonatype version of the M2E plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/). This is their Eclipse update site:

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/

It seems to be better integrated in Eclipse / Maven. See also this question here:

[How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin/6372575#6372575)