# Maven: No marketplace entries found to handle castor, antrun, and ear plugins

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, castor, maven-antrun-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

I am importing a maven project into Eclipse. I have the m2e plugin installed and it is pointing to maven 2.2.1 on my machine.

I am getting these three errors:

- No marketplace entries found to handle castor-maven-plugin:1.0:generate in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run in Eclipse
- No marketplace entries found to handle maven-ear-plugin:2.3.1:generate-application-xml in Eclipse

Any resources provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define [custom build](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered#execute_plugin_goal) life cycle mapping for those plugins and make m2eclipse execute certain goals during Eclipse build.

Answer (score 0):

This thread, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350414, contains a discussion and ultimately a patch to make eclipse capable of ignoring the connectors it can't find.

Most people on the thread find the m2e's demand for custom build life cycle mapping problematic.

Comment: How do you apply the patches?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and I resolved this by enclosing the  within the . Here is the example.

```
<build>
     <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                 ....
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Reference: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin#answer-13733232)