# Problems importing maven project in Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import maven project into Spring tool suite but during import - "Setup Maven Plugin Connectors" I am getting below error for three plugins:

> No marketplace entries found to handle maven-antrun-plugin:1.1:run in
>   Eclipse.   No marketplace entries found to handle
>   maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile in Eclipse.  No marketplace
>   entries found to handle maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile in
>   Eclipse.

I tried with solutions like adding IGNORE tag in POM.xml but it dosent work for me. 
Please Suggest.

Comment: I tried with solution provided in link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790044/maven-no-marketplace-entries-found-to-handle-castor-antrun-and-ear-plugins     &                           https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html

Comment: Please also tag eclipse, as it looks like eclipse is facing problem trying to download plugins it requires and not maven trying to download dependencies. Also, check your proxy settings, eclipse marketplace generally has problems if you are behind a proxy.