# m2e: convert project to maven project

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm trying to start with maven using `m2e plugin` for **eclipse**. But if I try to change existing project to Maven project (`Configure/Convert to Maven Project`), result is:

Multiple annotations found at this line:

- *Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out*
- *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)*
- *CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2: ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or  updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out*
- *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)*

I'm not behind the firewall (I was able to download and install m2e using eclipse installation interface).

Where could be the problem?

**UPDATE** (generated pom.xml):

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>PRJ</groupId>
  <artifactId>PRJ</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you paste the generated POM (I assume there is one)? Another thing: try to regenerate Eclipse project file by doing `Maven -> Update Project Configuration...` on the project.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Almost nothing is generated. And tha `Update Project Configuration` doesn't help. But in each classes of project are lost all the imports from `WEB=INF\lib` folder now..

Comment: The second and fourth message are related to m2e - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should actually remove all libs you have in `WEB-INF/lib` directory and add adequate `dependency` declarations in the POM. `WEB-INF` directory itself (and other web resources) should stay in `src/main/webapp`. If you have some non-Java files in `WEB-INF/classes`, move them into `src/main/resources`. After all, do Maven build on console by `mvn clean package` and tell if it works. It should. Then regenerate Eclipse project files by `Maven -> Update Project Configuration...`.

I don't believe in such tools for automagic migration of freestyle (mostly Ant) projects into Maven. As I see, it does nothing more that generate almost plain POM.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try it. I thought, that it will generate my pom.xml file automatically, without work :-)