# How can I get rid of the warning m2eclipse "goals inplace, exploded, manifest are ignored by m2e"

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse, eclipse-wtp

How can I get rid of the following m2eclipse warning?

```
maven-war-plugin goals "inplace", "exploded", "manifest" are ignored by m2e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this warning is being emitted from [m2e-wtp](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp), which provides a set of m2e connectors that work with Eclipse Web Tools Project (WTP).

m2e-wtp includes a [`lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml`](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/blob/master/org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp/lifecycle-mapping-metadata.xml) file that contains:

```xml
    <pluginExecution>
      <pluginExecutionFilter>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
        <goals>
          <goal>inplace</goal>
          <goal>exploded</goal>
          <goal>manifest</goal>
        </goals>
      </pluginExecutionFilter>
      <action>
        <ignore>
            <message>maven-war-plugin goals "inplace", "exploded", "manifest" are ignored by m2e</message>
        </ignore>
      </action>
    </pluginExecution>
  </pluginExecutions>
```

Thus, I don't think there is a way to suppress this warning, other than to (1) stop using m2e-wtp or (2) downgrade to version 0.14 of m2e-wtp, as this warning was [added](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MECLIPSEWTP-204) in 0.15.

Answer (score 3):

The following snippet worked for me:

```xml
<pluginExecution>
  <pluginExecutionFilter>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
      <goals>
        <goal>manifest</goal> <!-- put the goal you're executing in your pom.xml file -->
      </goals>
    </pluginExecutionFilter>
    <action>
      <ignore />
    </action>
</pluginExecution>
```

Comment: Very good! Info about where to put this `pluginExecution` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10836584/1850609

Comment: This has to go in this block,      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
     <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
     <configuration>
      <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
       <pluginExecutions>

Answer (score 1):

See if you can locate an m2e connector for the maven-war-plugin, or configure your POM to tell Eclipse to ignore it or run it anyway.  Later versions of m2e may include the connector you need so upgrading the plugin may help.  More details and background [in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin).

Comment: This isn't possible to fix with this plugin execution filters, at least it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just deleted this warning message by right-clicking it within the Problems View in Eclipse and it hasn't come back.

Updating my POM with the ignore action, as lehphyro did, didn't work for me.