# The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the ... ApplicationRequestFactory RequestFactory type

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, m2e

I want to use Spring ROO 1.2.1 + GWT 2.6.1 in Springsource Tool Suite 2.9.1 in Ubuntu 12.04.
Following guides like the video in http://www.bytespring.com/blog/spring-roo-integration-gwt, I can create with roo a new project via the "expense" script, then run it with mvn gwt:run.
Ok, than I want to manage it in STS and now the problem starts.
It seems to be problem about m2e.

In pom.xml the  tag for artifact with ID "exec-maven-plugin" have this error:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2:exec (execution: default, phase: process-classes)
```

I tried to follow the solution suggested in [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin).

Surrounded "plugins" tag with the "pluginManagement" tag. Now the error no longer appears.

Then I run the application, "Run as -> Web Application"... HTML Page Selection: ApplicationScaffold.html.

The web page appears, but with a window with this error:

```
Error: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCause".
```

The STS console says

```
"java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFactory ValidationTool must be run for the org.springsource.roo.extrack.client.managed.request.ApplicationRequestFactory RequestFactory type".
```

To solve this problem, I followed the instructions in http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation.

1)In Project Properties->Java Compiler->Annotation Properties I enabled project specific settings, annotation processing and processing in editor, gen.source directory: .apt_generated; verbose false.

2) In Factory Path, enabled project specific settings, and added the external requestfactory-apt.jar located in

```
/home/toni/springsource/sts-2.9.1.RELEASE/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205091048-rel-r37/gwt-2.4.0
```

(right??)

(I do not understand if "Validation Tool" and "Maven build" sections are important for me)

Now I tried to re-run (after a rebuild of project) and the same error persists.

Someone solved this problem?? How? Please explain step-by-step because I am not an expert, It's my first approach with spring and gwt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the same problem I ran into a short while back, which (after considerable digging) appeared to be down to [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344159) in AJDT (Eclipse's AspectJ compiler) which means that it currently cannot handle Java 6 annotations (used heavily by Roo).

[A comment](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7083#c5) on a connected GWT bug report describes the following workaround:

> 1. move AspectJ builder to be in front (on top) of Java builder in project properties, Builder page.
> 2. clean and build the project.
> 3. copy and save generated Java/class files in .apt_generated directory to somewhere else.
> 4. move Java builder back in front of AspectJ builder.
> 5. clean and rebuild the project
> 6. copy the class file from 3 above to your project's classpath.

Alternatively, you can build your project outside of Eclipse - the non-IDE AspectJ compiler, ajc, does not suffer from this problem.