# goal execution "generateAsync" is not recognized by gwt-maven-plugin in Maven

Tags: gwt, maven, mojo

I'm developing an application (Project A)  that consume some sources from Project B. The `pom.xml` of project A is:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.pe.interbank</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <relativePath>../reactor</relativePath>
</parent>

<properties>
    <path2>Reactor/pom.xml</path2>
    <path1>C:/Angelo/Workspace/MultipleGWTv2/Reactor/pom.xml</path1>
</properties>

<artifactId>webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>webapp</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- this is the dependency to the "jar"-subproject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pe.interbank</groupId>
        <artifactId>transferencias</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>catalina</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- GWT version detected from dependencyManagement -->
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <runTarget>com.pe.interbank.Inicio/Inicio.html</runTarget>
                <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                <optimizationLevel>1</optimizationLevel>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>war</warSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I got an error in the line `<execution>`:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:generateAsync (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)   pom.xml /IBKWebCore line 56 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

It seems that `generateAsync` goals is not founded in `gwt-maven-plugin`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: BTW, “GWT version detected from dependencyManagement” is plain wrong: since 2.1.0, gwt-maven-plugin is bound to a specific GWT version (plugin version is the same as the GWT version being used). If you use a different version, you have to override plugin dependencies: http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html