# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.datanucleus:maven-datanucleus-plugin:3.0.1:enhance (execution: default, phase: compile)

Tags: maven, execution, datanucleus, eclipse-juno

I m using eclipse Juno

Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

POM.xml shows error as: 
     Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.datanucleus:maven-
     datanucleus-plugin:3.0.1:enhance (execution: default, phase: compile)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>false</fork>
                <log4jConfiguration>${basedir}/log4j.properties</log4jConfiguration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <enhancerName>ASM</enhancerName>
                <!-- <api>JPA</api> -->
                <persistenceUnitName>applicatonPersistenceUnit</persistenceUnitName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>enhance</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Please advice... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about the background of this error from: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

In summary, m2e execution inside eclipse might not work as expected for some phases, and maven requires an explicit command (i.e. ignore, execute or delegate) in order to decide what to do at that phase.

Recent eclipse versions (I am using Kepler) provide a "Quick fix" option when you right click on the error, and it adds the `<pluginManagement>` setting in your pom file. You can replace            th `<ignore />` action with the suitable one, if you prefer to "execute" or "delagate".

A similar problem was discussed here: [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)