# Error in POM (eclipse osgi)

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I've been getting this maven error for a while now:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.cerner.engineering:cerner-    osgi-plugin:3.1.1:generate-osgi-manifest (execution: default, phase: 
 compile)
```

This is the snippet of my pom that is having the problem.

```
<execution>
    <goals>
        <goal>generate-osgi-manifest</goal>
        <goal>generate-test-osgi-manifest</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

Has anybody seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually configure a lifecycle mapping. The lifecycle mapping was introduced by m2e, so that Eclipse knows what to do with your Maven plugin, if you are building in Eclipse. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin).