# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration with m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm getting this error for my maven project with Eclipse (m2e plugin):

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:exploded (execution: default, phase: compile)  pom.xml /MyGWT S    line 642    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:generateAsync (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)   pom.xml /MyGWT  line 618    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin:2.4.0:i18n (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)    pom.xml /MyGWT  line 618    Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Should I fix this error by doing a "Ignore" or this is fixable with "Discover new m2e connectors"?

I tried doing a "discover" but it seems there is no plugin for this on the marketplace.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why m2e raise this `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: ...` message is explained in the following page in details:

[M2E plugin execution not covered](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)

Generally speaking, The way m2e used for resolving/mapping plugins' goal execution into Eclipse build life cycle has been reinvented after version 0.12. Now **m2e 1.0 requires explicit instructions what to do with all Maven plugins bound to "interesting" phases of a project build lifecycle.** By either configure the lifecycle mapping in your project's pom, or use specific m2e configurator Eclipse plugin if somebody has kindly created it for the community.

> Should I fix this error by doing a "Ignore" or this is fixable with "Discover new m2e connectors"?

Depend on your demand, if you don't expect Eclipse to run the complete build life cycle defined by Maven, just ignore it, otherwise configure each uncovered plugin execution properly (in case if there is no proper m2e configurator available), see the sample org.eclipse.m2e:lifecycle-mapping plugin configuration in that link.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have post-clean in your code like below.

```
   <executions>           
     <execution>
        <configuration></configuration>
        <phase>post-clean</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>......<your goal goes here>.....</goal>
        </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
```