# M2eclipse unable to detect instrument goal for process-classes phase

Tags: maven, m2eclipse, m2e, emma

I am configuring my Java project's pom.xml file to use the emma-maven-plugin for code coverage during builds. I use Eclipse Juno as my IDE and it uses M2eclipse for running Maven. I configured my plugin in the exact same way suggested on [their website](http://mojo.codehaus.org/emma-maven-plugin/usage.html):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
    <inherited>true</inherited>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that this plugin is in the `<build>` section of the pom. Anyways, I keep getting this error from Eclipse regarding using *instrument* as the goal:

`Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:emma-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:instrument (execution: default, phase: process-classes)`

I have been searching frantically for an m2e connector to download but to no avail. I also tried looking at SOF post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) but I'd highly prefer avoiding using an `<ignore>` tag in my `<pluginManagement>` if possible. Unless I really have to. Also note that my project builds fine and runs EMMA and all other plugins like normal when I run the Maven build, notwithstanding the error message.

What is the best way to deal with this error?