# Eclipse m2e connector for JAX-WS org.codehaus.mojo

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-juno, m2e, wsimport

I am trying to consume a webservice using `wsimport` goal declared at maven build. But I am facing the problem with `m2e connectors`. There is an error in my POM which says

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-
          plugin:1.10:wsimport (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
```

I have been trying to install m2e connectors but not getting them even in marketplace. There are other m2e connectors but not for JAX-WS which i need.

I have followed and tried almost each solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) but all in vain.

Although there is no problem in generating the resources. The resources are generated at build time successfully but this POM error **is not allowing** my project to get sync with my tomcat and each time I have to deploy the war manually to test even the little changes i make.

All this is really annoying and I need to figure out a solution to this. I am using eclipse juno in this.
Below is the POM file I am using

```
<build>
    <finalName>home</finalName>
    <plugins>       
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>post-clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <!-- -->
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://localhost:8080/email-service/services/EmailService?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated</sourceDestDir>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>additional-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/home/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/props</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a M2E jaxws-maven-connector GitHub project: https://github.com/trajano/jaxws-maven-connector . It worked for me with Eclipse Kepler and `org.codehaus.mojo:jaxws-maven-plugin:1.12`.

1. Choose *Install new Software* from the *Help* menu.
2. Add the repository `https://raw.github.com/trajano/jaxws-maven-connector/master/jaxws-connector-update-site/` (see [project](https://github.com/trajano/jaxws-maven-connector))
3. Install *m2e connector for jaxws* and restart.
4. Import the Maven project or update the Eclipse Maven project configuration.

Answer (score 5):

Vote for https://github.com/javaee/metro-jaxws-commons/issues/124 and get this fixed in the plugin.
Then you don't need a connector.

In the meantime you can hack this as per Archimedes Trajano's post

Comment: Ahh the internet how I love thee - I've come looking for answers to this question a year later and here is the answer, although adding m2e support has still not occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Though I did keep the [jaxws-maven-connector](https://github.com/trajano/jaxws-maven-connector) updated to work with the latest M2E and jaxws-maven-plugin, I found a better way (which I also posted on http://www.trajano.net/2013/12/jaxws-maven-plugin-and-m2e/)

You add the following profile to your pom.xml file to remove the need for a non-discoverable M2E plugin.

```
    <profile>
        <id>m2e</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>m2e.version</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-wsimport-sources</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/wsimport</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                                <pluginExecutions>
                                    <pluginExecution>
                                        <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                            <groupId>
                                                org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons
                                            </groupId>
                                            <artifactId>
                                                jaxws-maven-plugin
                                            </artifactId>
                                            <versionRange>
                                                [2.3.1-b03,)
                                            </versionRange>
                                            <goals>
                                                <goal>wsimport</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                        </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <action>
                                            <execute />
                                        </action>
                                    </pluginExecution>
                                </pluginExecutions>
                            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </pluginManagement>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

As for the jaxws-maven-plugin configuration, just keep it to the defaults as much as possible:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1-b03</version>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://www.webservicex.net/ConvertAcceleration.asmx?WSDL</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>wsimport</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```