# the "build automatically" and maven in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

in Eclipse, when Maven is enabled, there is a pom.xml file to build with Maven. And also, Eclipse has a "build automatically" option in it's project menu.

Is the "build automatically" automatically build with Maven, or we need uncheck it, because when Maven is enabled, we don't need the Eclipse build in build system anymore?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eclipse's *m2e* will run the plugin goals it has lifecycle bindings for. I don't know (and I'm unable to find) what specific phases are run, but from experience I know that:

- for normal operation, at least **compile** gets executed.
- for executing tests (e.g. JUnit test cases), at least **test-compile** gets executed.

Note that it doesn't have all possible bindings, and going around [that problem](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) is sometimes [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin?rq=1). So, usually, having both should run fine, and in fact will avoid some incongruities due to the compiled state not updating while you code.

**However** if you **have plugins that are ignored by m2e**, you should **actually shut down "Build Automatically" off** when you **need to be certain** your build completes correctly.

For example, using the [Maven Properties plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/), if you have not provided a binding and set `m2e` to ignore, you will have resources with out-of-whack property values. The problem can especially occur when you do a "Maven" build (from the right-click context menu for example), and then do a change in your code and save it.

Answer (score 1):

**You need both.** Here is why:

Eclipse built-in compiler is used for incremental compilation - when you save your code, for example. But full build of the project is done using maven and project configuration in pom.xml.

Comment: That's not true - `m2e` actually runs the lifecycle bindings it has, it's not only incremental code compilation. A trivial example here is resource filtering.