# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration AppEngine

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

Need help with the following Eclipse m2e issue:

Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.8.3:endpoints_get_discovery_doc (execution: default, phase: compile)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.3</version>
    <configuration>                                     
      <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      **<execution>**
        <goals>
          <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Any ideas? The pom.xml looks like: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-java-maven/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 2):

Put this inside the `<build>` section of your pom

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.8.3,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>endpoints_get_discovery_doc</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore></ignore>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Source: [M2Eclipse documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#ignore-plugin-goal)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered by [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

The only difference is that in your case you have to replace the pluginExecutionFilter tag with:

```
<pluginExecutionFilter>
    <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <versionRange>1.8.3</versionRange>
    <goals>
        <goal>test-compile</goal>
        <goal>compile</goal>
    </goal>
</pluginExecutionFilter>
```