# Pom error in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have a Maven project in Eclipse and if I try to run `Maven > Update project` I get the following error

> Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.net.ConnectException: connection timed out to http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom

- I tried to run Maven with the embedded installation and an external one - same result.
- I don't have any proxy set up in Eclipse and I don't need one.
- I do not reference the plugin in my POM.
- Running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in console works perfectly.
- I'm using Eclipse Kepler and m2e 1.4.0.201.

The parent POM is

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.sonatype.oss</groupId>
    <artifactId>oss-parent</artifactId>
    <version>7</version>
</parent>
```

Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: *You* may not be referencing the plugin, but the super POM might. I'm unclear whether you're saying if you tried this on the command-line and whether that worked or not? If you state: "don't need" "any proxy set up", do you mean that your computer has unrestricted access to the Internet?

Comment: The command line mvn eclipse:eclipse works perfectly. The computer has unrestricted access to Internet and all the sites are working in all browsers without a proxy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

solved the problem.

Comment: I don't understand why - but it also solved my problem. Does anybody have an explaination for this behaviour?

Comment: solved my problem too! I dont have any idea why... thanks! But i would like to unterstand why.. would be great if anyone could explain that

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error I was getting initially:

> Failure to transfer org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:9 from
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer   artifact org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:pom:9
>   from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Address family
>   not supported by protocol family: connect

I didn't need to introduce any additional maven plugins, simply enclosing the existing plugins inside `<pluginManagement>` tag as described here: [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin/13733232#13733232) solved it for me - hopefully it will help someone else as well.