# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:consume-aar

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-plugin

I've installed Eclipse Kepler then installed the Android Development Toolkit and the M2E Android Connector Plugin so I can manage my android projects with maven. However, when I
create a new project I'm getting the following error:

```
 Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:consume-aar
```

This kinda strange because the M2E Android Connector is installed so what is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because you are using Maven you might want to try Android Studio. I find the Maven support to be solid. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: Have you seen this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) ?

Comment: Please check this : http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Answer (score 4):

The reason of the problem you are facing is that handling `consume-aar` goal is not yet implemented in m2e-android (Android Connector for M2E).

Here is the relevant [m2e-android ticket](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/177) for this, witch is in turn  blocked by fact that ADT does not implement AAR support ([ADT ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=59183)).

Until these tickets are fixed there is a [workaround](https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/177#issuecomment-29821049) for this but I cannot guarantee that it will work in all cases (basically it tells Maven integration with Eclipse to skip problematic build step).

An alternative solution would be to opt out for Android Studio (as far as I know it is implemented there).

Hope this will help.