# How can I deploy from within STS 3.5.1 (Spring Tool Suite) to a remote GlassFish 4 server?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, remote-server, glassfish-4, spring-tool-suite

I use Netbeans 8 and can deploy to my debian server, by just clicking the play button.

Now I want to be able to do the same from within the spring tool suite.

So what do I have to do?

UPDATE (2014-06-30):
This helped me: http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/11/04/continuous-integration-and-deployment-using-git-maven-jenkins-and-glassfish/

Then I learned that you have to install a local glassfish server so that you can use the asadmin / asadmin.bat to deploy to a remote glassfish server. That worked for me with netbeans and maven.

One problem is that the description of adding a custom maven goal is IDE specific, but I could enter that at 'Run -> Run Configurations -> Maven Build'

> Enter the following Maven Goals: ‘properties:read-project-properties clean install glassfish:redeploy -e’. In the Properties text box, enter the following: ‘glassfish.properties.file.argument=testing’

I imported the working netbeans/maven project to STS and another problem with maven is described here: [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

UPDATE (2014-07-06):
I guess I just got confused with the need to have a server installed locally. So just adding a glassfish server with the ip address of the remote-server as host name seems to do the trick. Maybe it helped configuring a server on localhost before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a plugin for Eclipse for the Glassfish server and maybe that supports the remote deployment. Did you take a look at that? Since the Spring Tool Suite is Eclipse plus a few Spring-specific add-ons, you should be able to use general Eclipse plugins for Glassfish (or others) with STS as well.

Comment: I already installed
GlassFish Tools for Eclipse
and
Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse,
but I could not find a way to use them for remote deployment.

Comment: In that case I would hope for those guys to show up here and maybe have an idea how to do that. We don't do anything special for Glassfish in STS, but directly re-use what comes from Glassfish for Eclipse.