# Error in Eclipse Luna in m2e plugin when adding dependency to AspectJ

Tags: eclipse, maven, aspectj

I'm trying to use AspectJ in my project. When I try to add the maven plugin aspectj-maven-plugin in my pom.xml, I get this error:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.7:compile (execution: default, phase: compile)

I already tried to install the AspectJ toolkit + AspectJ m2e connector, but then I get an error at every annotation, because the compile level seems to be not 1.5 or above.

My setup is: Eclipse Luna + Java EE7 + JDK8.

My pom.xml

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.dickschmeck</groupId>
<artifactId>housekeepingbook-web</artifactId>
<version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Web Project</name>
<description>Web Project</description>

<properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <log4j.version>2.0.2</log4j.version>
    <primefaces.version>4.0</primefaces.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Java EE 7 dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSR-330 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>prime-repo</id>
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>

    <plugins>
        <!-- Avoid war plugin complaining missing web.xml -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                <hostname>${wildfly-hostname}</hostname>
                <port>${wildfly-port}</port>
                <username>${wildfly-username}</username>
                <password>${wildfly-password}</password>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

</build>
```

Thank you very much in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is more a problem or quirk of the m2e plugin and is nothing specific to aspectj - which is also the reason it works in @kriegaex 's IntelliJ IDEA.

Here's a relevant site of the Eclipse-Wiki explaining the cause: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) is about the same problem and one possible solution appears to be to add a corresponding `<pluginManagement>`-tag as described in the highest voted answer.

Also keep in mind that this error only pertains to the build of your application *in Eclipse*. It has no bearing on the maven build and can be safely ignored if you only ever build your project via maven - the quick fixes suggested for the error by Eclipse should give the option to ignore the error.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your problem exactly, but maybe it helps if I tell you that in order to get an AJDT (AspectJ Development Tools) version for Luna, currently you need to use a snapshot/developer version available from

http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update/

The POM as such seems to be okay, at least it works on an empty project in IntelliJ IDEA or from the Maven command line.