# replacer Maven issue with lifecycle phases

Tags: java, android, maven, lifecycle

Can't compile the following pom.xml plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.3</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals><goal>replace</goal></goals>                   
            <phase>process-sources</phase>                  
        </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
        <ignoreMissingFile>false</ignoreMissingFile>
        <file>target/generated-sources/r/com/actionbarsherlock/R.java</file>
        <outputFile>target/generated-sources/r/com/actionbarsherlock/R.java</outputFile>
        <regex>false</regex>
        <token>static final int</token>
        <value>static int</value>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Receive the following error:
**Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.3:replace (execution: default, phase: process-sources)  pom.xml /ActionBarSherlock  line 67 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem**

We tried different plugins, but we can never get to make it work in the "process-sources" phase. Looks like this phase has something special or needs to be configured somehow?

Add some details by request:
IDE: ADT v22
Maven version: 3.0.4

The error is signaled on the POM.xml next to the 'executions' line. If I change the *process-sources* phase to *prepare-package*, the error disappears. Unfortunately at that point the replacement is useless.

Comment: Which Maven version do you use? Can you show the full error output?

Comment: Updated with some more details. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your whole POM file? I just tried it on a project as you've typed it (replaced with a source file of my own) and it worked fine. Suggest trying suggestions found in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: The problem was that we imported the Sherlock project as a Maven project, instead it should be imported as ADT project.
Thanks a lot for helping!