# maven in command line succeed, but failed when using the same maven in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, hadoop

I'm trying to build the project of hadoop. I followed the official document as follows on how to do that.

```
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowToContribute
https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment
```

I've `git clone` the project, `maven install` it successfully, but when I import the project, or even a sub-project like 'hadoop-yarn-api', I got the following errors on maven:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (execution: compile-protoc, phase: generate-sources) pom.xml /hadoop-yarn-api line 73 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

Then I'm trying to `mvn clean install` the project via `External Tools Configuration` in eclipse, it also failed on:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT:protoc (compile-protoc) on project hadoop-yarn-api: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 'protoc --version' did not return a version -> [Help 1]
```

But the curious part is that when I `cd` into the root directory of 'hadoop-yarn-api' and invoke `mvn clean install`, it can be built successfully.

I'm using m2ecipse in eclipse, and I'm sure that I've changed to the maven which is exactly the one that I'm used in command line, not the embedded one.

And I've installed protocol buffers 2.5.0:

```
$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.5.0
```

Could anyone give me some idea? Many thanks!

**P.S.**

Eclipse Java EE IDE - Juno Service Release 2

m2e - 1.4.1.20140328-1905

Mac 1- 0.9.4

maven - 3.0.5

Hadoop - 2.2.0

Comment: Which version of Eclipse and which version of m2e integration? Which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds].  Even though this question is about Spring, the underlying issue (and answer) is the same.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: Have already appended to my post. @khmarbaise

Comment: Sorry, nothing worked for me in that thread. @ChrisGerken