# Errors after building project using maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I followed the following tutorial (https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype) and imported the project to eclipse.

However, i am getting the following errors in my pom.xml file, and also in all the java classes.

I have attached the screenshot.

POM.xml

[image]

[image]

Java classes

[image]

I have updated my Post

**PROBEM VIEW**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: I tired that, but no use.

Comment: Build project manually from command line. Import to eclipse as maven project. Run clean/ maven update.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the eclipse buildpath, make sure you have the maven dependency jars downloaded  under "Maven Dependencies"
   If you dont see, run the below command to download the same.
   mvn clean dependency:copy-dependencies package
2. This may sound silly, but in my experience I have seen this working. Do a Project Clean in eclipse and do a maven build

Answer (score 0):

There is no Maven dependencies classfolder in your screenshot. Have you tried right-clicking the project name -> Maven -> Update Project?

**Update Unbound classpath var.M2_REPO**

You need to fix your Maven installation. Go to Window -> Preferences -> Maven and have a look at: Installations and UserSettings

Comment: Yes  i did that several times. But no luck

Comment: What does the "Problems" view tell you about the errors (Eclipse -> Window -> Show View -> Other -> Problems)? That lifecycle thing is only a warning, not the problem.

Comment: I have updated my post with the problem view. Please have a look.