# Could not transfer artifact jlibs:jlibs-xml:pom:1.0 from/to kepler

Tags: maven, eclipse-kepler, myeclipse

I am running the pom.xml with in the Myeclipse window. Getting the error related to Kepler repository. Not sure why I am seeing this error. Please refer the error stack below -

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3:generate-raml (default) on project Service: Execution default of goal org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3:generate-raml failed: Plugin org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:1.3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies for org.raml.plugins:jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.3 (): Failed to read artifact descriptor for jlibs:jlibs-xml:jar:1.0: Could not transfer artifact jlibs:jlibs-xml:pom:1.0 from/to kepler (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler): No connector available to access repository kepler (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler) of type p2 using the available factories AsyncRepositoryConnectorFactory, WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory -> [Help 1]
```

I am using the below maven code -

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.raml.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxrs-raml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.3.3</version>
<configuration>
    <sourcePaths>
        <param>${basedir}/src/main/java/Service.java</param>
    </sourcePaths>
    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxrs-raml/example.raml</outputFile>
</configuration>    
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate-raml</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>process-classes</phase>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

---

Not facing similar while running the plug in code for "raml-jaxrs-maven-plugin"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a maven issue. Have you tried searching for parts of your error (e.g. "No connector available to access repository" p2)? The results may reveal some relevant information.

Comment: Hey Tony, Thanks for your reply. As far as I understand Jars is having dependency on the content which is available on KEPLER repository not on maven central repo. Is there any way from where maven central repo can copy the jars from kepler repo.

Comment: Sorry, you'll need a maven expert to help; I try to help with MyEclipse specific issues. However, maybe this is of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13733232/767143