# Plugin execution not covered - maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm trying to develop a plugin for maven using Mojo
with the following command line:

```
 mvn archetype:generate \
      -DgroupId=sample.plugin \
      -DartifactId=hello-maven-plugin \
      -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes \
      -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-plugin
```

But when importing the project for Eclipse, as shown below:

[image]

I get the following message in eclipse:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (execution: default-descriptor, phase: generate-resources)
```

My pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>sample.plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

  <name>hello-maven-plugin Maven Plugin</name>

  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>3.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
      <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.8.2</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <goalPrefix>hello-maven-plugin</goalPrefix>
          <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>mojo-descriptor</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>help-goal</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>helpmojo</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>run-its</id>
      <build>

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
              <debug>true</debug>
              <cloneProjectsTo>${project.build.directory}/it</cloneProjectsTo>
              <pomIncludes>
                <pomInclude>*/pom.xml</pomInclude>
              </pomIncludes>
              <postBuildHookScript>verify</postBuildHookScript>
              <localRepositoryPath>${project.build.directory}/local-repo</localRepositoryPath>
              <settingsFile>src/it/settings.xml</settingsFile>
              <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
              </goals>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>integration-test</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>install</goal>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>

      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Form of maven by Ubuntu installation:

```
$> sudo apt-get install maven
```

How can I solve this problem? Where am I wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Answer (score 1):

I used eclipse quickfix himself to ignore and is now operating normally.