# Preferences -> Google -> App Engine keeps returning to original config + plugin execution problems

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, google-app-engine

I've been struggling so hard with Maven lately.

**Issue #1)**

I keep getting

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type The App Engine SDK
>   'C:\Users\Paulo.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.24\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24.jar'
>   on the project's build path is not valid (SDK location
>   'C:\Users\Paulo.m2\repository\com\google\appengine\appengine-api-1.0-sdk\1.9.24\appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.24.jar'
>   is not a directory)   jotageorcamento     Unknown Google App Engine Problem

even though I have tried changing the config under preferences as shown below. Does anyone know where I can find this file and change it brute-forcefully?

[image: tried changing the location here]

**Issue #2)**

Normally, my Eclipse gives me

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Plugin execution not covered
>   by lifecycle configuration:
>   com.google.appengine:appengine-maven-plugin:1.9.24:endpoints_get_discovery_doc
>   (execution: default, phase: compile)  pom.xml /jotageorcamento    line
>   187   Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
>
> AND
>
> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Plugin execution not covered
>   by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.1:display-dependency-updates
>   (execution: default, phase: compile)  pom.xml /jotageorcamento    line
>   134   Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

It runs both on Eclipse and through terminal with `mvn appengine:devserver`.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) post, and tried adding `<pluginManagement>` to get rid of this problem. It turned out that `mvn appengine:devserver` started giving

[image: This]

I would appreciate some help since I dug so much trying to find the solution, but nothing brought it to an end.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and changing the order of the classpath entries in the `.classpath` fixed it.

The google app engine entry **MUST BE BEFORE** the Maven classpath entry. Reload and rebuild the project and you will get rid of #1, and it will probably also fix the #2 (no warranty...)

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
<classpathentry kind="con" 
path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.26"/>
```

must be

```
<classpathentry kind="con" 
path="com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.GAE_CONTAINER/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.26"/>
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

Comment: Ok, some points that I noticed. My .classpath doesn't contain any entry pointing to GAE_CONTAINER/appengine-java-sdk-x. I added it but the problem log persists. Ps. Now I am able to change the config so +1