# I have an error in pom.xml file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I got an error that is shown in picture [image: when i added this code it gives me a error the image show that what is the error ?]

you can see error in the picture that i given this error comes at line where i write a packaging tag when i remove this tag then error come at this point (http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd)
here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.github.haifengl</groupId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<artifactId>smile-plot</artifactId>
<version>1.1.0</version>

<name>Smile Plot</name>
<description>Statistical Machine Intelligence and Learning Engine -- Plot</description>
<url>http://github.com/haifengl/smile</url>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <name>Haifeng Li</name>
        <email>haifeng.hli@gmail.com</email>
        <url>http://haifengl.wordpress.com</url>
        <roles>
            <role>architect</role>
            <role>developer</role>
        </roles>
        <timezone>America/New_York</timezone>
        <properties>
            <twitter>@haifengl</twitter>
        </properties>
    </developer>
</developers>

<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:haifengl/smile.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:haifengl/smile.git</developerConnection>
    <url>git@github.com:haifengl/smile.git</url>
</scm>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.haifengl</groupId>
        <artifactId>smile-math</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.haifengl</groupId>
        <artifactId>smile-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>doclint-java8-disable</id>

        <activation>
            <jdk>[1.8,)</jdk>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.10.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sign</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
                <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
                <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: Is forgetting `</project>` a mistake while copy/pasting?

Comment: it can't shown i paste that here