# How to configure maven in eclipse mars

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, svn

I install a eclipse mars and download maven plugins but when I create my first app in pom it is showing the error
 Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: **org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)**

I try all possibility but can not resolve so what is the solutation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M2Eclipse provides a quick-fix associated with “**plugin execution not covered**” to easily create `<pluginManagement/>` elements

You can visit these links for more information.

1. [https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html#ignore-plugin-goal)

2. [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Hope this will work.