# Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, zinc

While compiling the Maven project the following error occured:

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10 --- 
[WARNING] Zinc server is not available at port 3030 - reverting to normal incremental compile 
[INFO] Using incremental compilation 
[INFO] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /home/gorlec/Desktop/test/external/flume-sink/target/scala-2.10/classes... 
[ERROR] /home/gorlec/Desktop/test/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkAvroCallbackHandler.scala:47: identifier expected but 'with' found. 
[ERROR] with Logging { 
[ERROR] ^ 
[ERROR] one error found 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 7.992s 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 15 17:44:33 CEST 2016 
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/350M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed -> 
[Help 1] 
[ERROR]
```

I removed the property `<useZincServer>true</useZincServer>` from pom.xml, and still the Logging error persists.

```
[INFO] --- scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) @ spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10 --- 
[INFO] Using incremental compilation 
[INFO] Compiling 6 Scala sources and 3 Java sources to /home/gorlec/Desktop/test/external/flume-sink/target/scala-2.10/classes... 
[ERROR] /home/gorlec/Desktop/test/external/flume-sink/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/flume/sink/SparkAvroCallbackHandler.scala:47: identifier expected but 'with' found. 
[ERROR] with Logging { 
[ERROR] ^ 
[ERROR] one error found 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] Total time: 5.814s 
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Apr 15 17:41:00 CEST 2016 
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/335M 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed -> 
[Help 1] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I checked that `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` are defined in `~/.bashrc` as follows:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

The only issue that I noticed is that `echo $JAVA_HOME` gives an empty output, though I did `source ~/.bashrc`.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to compile spark-streaming-flume-sink_2.10 locally ?

What are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be this `[INFO] Using incremental compilation`

In your pom.xml try to remove the line 
`<recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>`

and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange echo $JAVA_HOME gives an empty output.While compling the Spakr Source,I import the mvn clean package success porject into eclipse,I meet the same problem.And I found the solution here:
[How to solve “Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration” for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Answer (score 0):

I think you were compiling Spark with Scala 2.10. If so, you should do as follows.

```
cd /path/to/Spark
./dev/change-scala-version.sh 2.10
./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dscala-2.10 -DskipTests clean package
```

Hope this helps.