# Maven build error with hive and spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark, hive

I am trying to use hive on spark, rev combination is hive 2.1.1 and spark 2.0.0. In building spark without hive, blocked by same building error as below. Even latest spark 2.1.0, still same issue.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException:
Execution default-cli of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed
```

There is another question of same issue([Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651611/failed-to-execute-goal-net-alchim31-mavenscala-maven-plugin3-2-2)), i checked and did everything in this post including commenting out Zinc in pom.xml. Still no luck to bypass this.

Any one can help with this weird  net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin issue?

Comment: BTW, this error always pop out in building of spark-streaming-flume-sink

Comment: Can you provide more log output ? (your message is not the same as in the issue you linked)

Comment: @David, here are the logs

Comment: Can you share the full console output (and also run maven with -e), not only the 2 lines ?

Comment: I may be wrong here, since I'm also dealing with similar problems, but hive 2.1 doesn't seem to be compatible with spark 2, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43786951/3629151).