# want to run exec-maven-plugin when spring-boot running

Tags: maven, spring-boot, exec-maven-plugin

My Spring-boot project structure is below

`-Project
 - src
      - main
        - java
        - resources
        - webapp
      - test
 - frontend
      - src
      - static
      - config
      - package.json
      - (after "npm install") node_modules
      - (after "npm run build") dist`

what I want to do is

1. when a project is installed, run "npm install"
2. when "spring-boot:run" runs, run "npm run build" and moves contents in front/dist to /main/webapp

here is my pom.xml

```
    <build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>exec-npm-install</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <executable>npm</executable>
                        <workingDirectory>./frontend</workingDirectory>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>install</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

I don't know how can I trigger exec-npm-install exection
with Eclipse maven build, I tried generate-sources, spring-boot:run, install and compile, package but it didn't run.

and I want to know what command should I put, to move dist when "spring-boot:run"

Comment: You need to move that out of the pluginManagement area. In pluginManagement you can define the versions and parameters but you need to put it outside of pluginManagement.

Comment: Thank you. in Eclipse, without pluginManagement, execution occurs error message, so I put them in it. now, as your comment, I removed pluginManagement and ignore execution error. it works!

Comment: What kind of execution error do you get?

Comment: [How to solve “Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration” for Spring Data Maven Builds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) I referenced it.

Answer (score 0):

Few things -

- As pointed by @khmarbaise as well, you should move your `<plugins>` tree out of the `<pluginManagement>` and also use `<version>` for the plugins you are using.
- > I don't know how can I trigger exec-npm-install exection

Since the execution is tied to the `generate-sources` phase of the execution. If you try and execute `mvn generate-sources` from command line on the project directory, you shall get the execution triggered. Also executing `mvn test`, `mvn install`, `mvn package` should do the needful. Take a look at the [Maven - Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference) for this.

- > I want to know what command should I put, to move dist when
  >   "spring-boot:run"

If you want to copy the resources to the `/webapp` directory, you shall take a look at [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html) and change its phase accordingly.