# Google Cloud Sample App - Plugin not covered by lifecycle configuration

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-cloud-platform, m2eclipse

I am trying to build the JAVA sample apps provided for Google Cloud Platform at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/storage/cloud-client

I have installed maven 3.5 and was able to build and run it from the command line with the steps mentioned in the README

However when I try to import and build the project in eclipse, I get the following error in the pom.xml :

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile)    pom.xml /datastore-google-cloud-samples line 23 Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem
```

The details of eclipse I am using are:

Version: 
Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

Build id: 20170314-1500

I looked at the following answer:
[How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin/6372575#6372575)

and added the pluginManagement tag in my pom.xml, however I still got the same error.

Is there any step which I am missing here?

Is there any particular setting which needs to be done in eclipse to use it with maven and/or google cloud?

Comment: Can you share the `pluginManagement` snippet you've added?