# Problems starting up Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite, netflix-eureka

I am trying to set up a Zuul gateway with a Eureka Server and several clients.

So far, I have created the Gateway and and initial Client without problems, but for some reason i keep getting an error when I try to start the registry.

As far as I can tell, the problem has to do with loading the configuration, with the root being that the class `com/sun/jersey/core/util/FeaturesAndProperties` is not found.

I have tried defining the Jersey components explicitly, but no matter how I set up the pom (jersey before the spring imports, jersey after the imports, different versions) I get the same issue.

I have also tried different release trains, based on this page http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/ and read up on the different dependencies.

I have also tried following the guide illustrated here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka (I am aware that the version is different, I have adjusted the values to several other release trains)

At this time, the jersey imports are present in the Maen dependencies section, with the pom.xml shown below. (see screenshot)

[image: jersey files in maven dependencies]

I am a little baffled as to why i can't get this to run. any help would be appreciated, or a point to a guide with more details.

it is worth mentioning that my application.yml is deduced from my readings, and i get the same error with a blank application.yml (or application.properties, which i have deleted)

Repository at https://github.com/JoSSte/MyEurekaRegistry

This is the error line as defined in the Console:

`2018-01-07 13:05:59.334 ERROR 5708 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter    : 
Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyFilterRegistration' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jerseyFilterRegistration' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jerseyApplication' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.ws.rs.core.Application]: Factory method 'jerseyApplication' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/core/util/FeaturesAndProperties`

**MyRegistryApplication.java**

```
package com.example.backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class MyRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyRegistry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>MyRegistry</name>
    <description>My Gateway</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

EDIT # 1:

based on this question, [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) I Decided to list my dependencies (`mvn dependency:list | grep jersey`) and see if there are conflicting versions of Jersey in my dependencies:

```
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-servlet:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-apache-client4:jar:1.19.1:runtime
[INFO]    com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:runtime
```

As this list indicates, I have the same version of Jersey. Besides that, I have no jax-rs, nor any glassfish in my dependencies

Comment: I found http://tomee.apache.org/tip-jersey-client.html but I am unsure where I can define this...

Comment: I also tried https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/solved-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-jersey-spi-container-servlet-servletcontainer/ as stated in my original question ( with relevant versions ofc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading on, and discovering loads of references to Tomcat classpaths, I decided to try to run the code in a different environment.

I started up a Ubuntu Virtual machine, downloaded Spring Tool Suite and cloned [the repository](https://github.com/JoSSte/MyEurekaRegistry) into that. I ran the project and it started up without any ado.

I have now uninstalled all the Glassfish servers, Tomcat servers, JDKs and JREs present on my PC and I am in the process of reinstalling a specific JDK and going through my environment variables to make sure that my classpath is "clean", which expect wil solve the issue.

Going through my local Maven repository (`C:\Users\username\.m2\repository`) and removing all folders relating to glassfish, and jersey (with the IDE shut down), and then startng the IDE, and running maven update (alt+F5) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly this had to be done for `Spring Cloud Camden`. I don't know if this has been fixed in recent releases.

Could you try this in the `Eureka` server:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <requiresUnpack>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-core</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </requiresUnpack>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got it working without changing my pom.xml further. clearing my maven repo solved it. as i wrote in my own answer, the thing that solved it was realizing that another jersey class was in the classpath. after realizing that a vanilla installation of spring on an ubuntu which worked with the same project, without any ado.