# maven goal issue with active jdbc

Tags: mysql, maven, spring-boot, activejdbc, javalite

While adding instrumentation plugin in pom.xml am getting this error

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.13:instrument (execution: default, phase: process-classes
```

If added all plugin inside pluginManagement then no error but this package org.javalite.activejdbc.Model not importing can you please assist me.

[image]

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin).

However, JavaLite documentation provides a [more concrete set of instructions for Eclipse configuration](http://javalite.io/eclipseIntegration).