# How to fix Prebid server-java package build error

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I am setting up a prebid server package to create a bidding adapter.
https://github.com/rubicon-project/prebid-server-java.git.

Prebid-server-java project is cloned,but I cant able to build and run.It shows some dependency issues on maven plugin.
It is showing package error as __ cannot be resolved to a type in all classes.
How can I fix this issue to build the package.

[Once the project is cloned,it shows the following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0dqy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems your embedded Maven of Eclipse doesn't know how handle download-maven-plugin.
Please, download Maven manually and set Eclipse to use it.

Go to Window -> Preference -> Maven -> Installation -> choose your own maven installation folder there.

Then try right click on project and run Maven -> Update Project.

Comment: Please, see similar thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin