# plugin execution not covered by lifecycle error

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Below is my pom.xml snippet

```
<parent> ---Getting Error Here
<groupId>com.Brink</groupId>
<artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
```

Error is: `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.mojo:flatten-maven-plugin:1.0:flatten (execution: flatten, phase: process-resources)`

May I now please, What's wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Post your full pom please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)