# Eclipse m2e fail where maven build succeeds - due to plugin execution not covered by lifecycle?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I have a project where maven build from eclipse m2e fails, but mvn clean install from the command line succeeds.

Its a multi module project ( parent and children ) which defines several custom executions.

I think the problem may be the result of several plugins showing errors of type "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration".

Furthermore upon import of the project a dialog comes up called "Setup Maven plugin connectors" and shows the goals with the custom executions as having no market place entries to handle them.

[image: uncoved goals]

I have read

[How to solve "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" for Spring Data Maven Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

and used "ignore" on the errors in eclipse maven preferences, which makes the errors go away, but the project is apparently not built correctly. Is there a more appropriate solution?

Here are shortened poms showing example of an uncovered goal. The parent pom defines a custom compile goal execution called compile_with_aspectj

```
<project xmlns=...xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>groupid</groupId>
            <artifactId>child-module-1</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>11</complianceLevel>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*.aj</include>
                    </includes>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <forceAjcCompile>true</forceAjcCompile>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <sources/>
                    <weaveDirectories>
                        <weaveDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</weaveDirectory>
                    </weaveDirectories>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile_with_aspectj</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

which then produces the following error in eclipse m2e

> Plugin execution not covered
> by lifecycle configuration:
> com.nickwongdev:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.12.6:compile (execution:
> compile_with_aspectj, phase:
> compile)  pom.xml /child-module-1 line 7  Maven Project Build
> Lifecycle Mapping Problem

where the child pom looks something like

```
 <project xmlns=..../xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>child-module-1</artifactId>
    <name>${project.groupId}:${project.artifactId}</name>
    <description> </description>
    <parent>
        <groupId>groupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-module</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
     ...
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.nickwongdev</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Does anyone know if m2e has a problem building projects with custom execution steps or with multi module projects?

Comment: The "Resolve Later" label is actually a dropdown, which you can set with different values for each plugin.  If there really is no connector for a plugin, then you'll probably have to set it to ignore.  However, I would recommend NOT choosing the "ignore in pom" choice. I prefer the "Ignore in workspace" option, as it doesn't change the source of your project. From a quick look at the collection, I don't see an aspectj plugin connector, but I do see a dependency plugin connector. I don't know about the others.

Answer (score 0):

Providing lifecycle metadata inside the *execution* node resolved similar error in eclipse in my case.

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <?m2e execute?>
        <id>generate-sources</id>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Refer [this](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/release-notes-17.html#new-syntax-for-specifying-lifecycle-mapping-metadata) for other lifecycle mapping options.