# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration from module projects

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have the main project, called **yyy**.

I have a subproject, a module called **yyy-common-test**.

Both are recognized as Maven projects. As you can see in the pic, the module identifies the parent Maven project and knows where is **org.codehous.groovy.maven** but yet cannot resolve from the **pom** file :

```
Plugin execution is not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehous.groovy.maven
```

I have tried Project Clean and Maven update (I don't see Maven Dependencies Update where it is) and still, I have this error on all my modules in the pom file.

[image]

Configuration:
[image]

```
Eclipse Photon Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: 4.8.0.20180619-1200
Build id: 20180619-1200
Maven: apache-maven-3.9.4
org.eclipse.m2e.feature (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse"
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "m2e logback configuration"
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP"
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs.feature (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JAX-RS Configurator"
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JPA Configurator"
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf.feature (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JSF Configurator"
org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver.feature (0.17.2.201606141937-signed-20160830073346) "m2e connector for the mavenarchiver and pom properties"
...
org.apache.maven.resolver.api (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver API" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.connector.basic (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver Connector Basic" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.impl (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver Implementation" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.spi (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver SPI" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.file (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver Transport File" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.http (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver Transport HTTP" [Resolved]
org.apache.maven.resolver.util (1.0.3.v20170405-0725) "Maven Artifact Resolver Utilities" [Resolved]
...
org.eclipse.aether.maven (3.1.0.v20140706-2237) "Maven Aether Provider Bundle" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common (1.9.0.20180606-2035) "Maven Archetype Common Bundle" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Bundle-Name" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.binaryproject.ui (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Bundle-Name" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.core (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.discovery (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "m2e Marketplace" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.editor (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors)" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven POM XML Editor" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.importer (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "m2e extension for import framework" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.jdt (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT UI" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.launching (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse Launching" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Default Build Lifecycle Mapping Metadata" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "m2e logback appender" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "m2e logback configuration" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer (1.9.0.20180606-2035) "Maven / Nexus Indexer Bundle" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime (1.9.0.20180606-2035) "Embedded Maven Runtime Bundle (includes Incubating components)" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple (1.9.0.20180606-2035) "slf4j-simple for use in m2e embedded maven runtime" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Project Model Edit Bundle" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Profiles Management" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Profiles Management UI" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Maven Integration for Eclipse Refactoring" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.scm (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "SCM Maven Integration for Eclipse" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.sourcelookup (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Bundle-Name" [Starting]
org.eclipse.m2e.sourcelookup.ui (1.9.0.20180606-2036) "Bundle-Name" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.workspace.cli (0.3.1) "m2e-workspace" [Resolved]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JAX-RS Configurator" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JPA Configurator" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Maven JSF Configurator" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.overlay (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Overlay support for Eclipse WTP" [Active]
org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.overlay.ui (1.4.0.20180606-2005) "Overlay support for Eclipse WTP - UI" [Starting]
org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver (0.17.2.201606141937-signed-20160830073346) "m2e connector for the mavenarchiver and pom properties" [Resolved]
...
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.defaultRuntime=apache-maven-3.9.4
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.runtimes=apache-maven-3.9.4
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.runtimesNodes/apache-maven-3.9.4/location=C\:\\Users\\milinma\\AppData\\Local\\Apache\\apache-maven-3.9.4
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.core/eclipse.m2.runtimesNodes/apache-maven-3.9.4/type=EXTERNAL
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery/org.eclipse.m2e.discovery.pref.projects=
/instance/org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml/org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml.templates=<?xml version\="1.0" encoding\="UTF-8" standalone\="no"?><templates/>
...
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.api, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.api_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.connector.basic, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.connector.basic_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.impl, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.impl_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.spi, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.spi_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.file, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.file_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.http, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.transport.http_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.apache.maven.resolver.util, Version: 1.0.3.v20170405-0725, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.apache.maven.resolver.util_1.0.3.v20170405-0725.jar
Id: org.eclipse.aether.maven, Version: 3.1.0.v20140706-2237, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.aether.maven_3.1.0.v20140706-2237.jar
Id: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer, Version: 1.9.0.20180606-2035, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.9.0.20180606-2035/
Id: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime, Version: 1.9.0.20180606-2035, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.9.0.20180606-2035/
Id: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple, Version: 1.9.0.20180606-2035, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple_1.9.0.20180606-2035/
Id: org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver, Version: 0.17.2.201606141937-signed-20160830073346, Location: reference:file:plugins/org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver_0.17.2.201606141937-signed-20160830073346.jar
```

Comment: I would recommend to upgrade your Eclipse version...

Comment: Could you try `pluginManagement` as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin)

Comment: @khmarbaise, I have to have what they have...I can use Oxygen or Photon as EE and I need EE. The funny thing is that it works fine in Eclipse Developer R2022-03 but not in Eclipse Photon EE

Comment: @WLefever, i cannot change the code, only configuration, files or Eclipse

Comment: Eclipse Photon is more than 5 years and 20 releases behind. Maven and the Maven support in Eclipse have evolved a lot since then, which also affects what you are asking (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/eclipse-m2e/m2e-core/blob/master/RELEASE_NOTES.md)). Please upgrade and support the open source software you use by not asking questions about outdated versions, but about the latest version only. Currently, the latest Eclipse version is [2023-06](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the plugin wasn't under build/pluginManagement/plugins but was under build/plugins

```
<build>
    <plugins>
     WAS HERE!!!!!
    </plugins>    
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>...
```